# Drawer List Array Adapter crashes app

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, navigation-drawer

I'm facing a problem regarding the Navigation Drawer menu implementation for Android. Right when I attempt to populate the left menu options with a String list (or array, both do not work) through an String Adapter, the application crashes so fast that LogCat catches no messages.

The Main Activity erroneous part:

```
package edu.getjedi.frontend.mobile;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainMapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
private UserLocationHandler locationHandler;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<>();

    test.add("abc");
    test.add("def");
    test.add("ghi");

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    // Set the list's click listener
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerMenuHandler());
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_main, test)); // Trouble is here!!
}

(...)
```

If I comment the `mDrawerList.setAdapter(...)` line, everything else works just fine.

---

The layout/activity_main.xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- The main content view -->
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="edu.getjedi.frontend.mobile.MainMapActivity" />
<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The guide I followed:
[Navigation Drawer - Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

What's the difference between the tutorial and my code sample?
 - The FrameLayout is a map fragment containing a pointer to MainMapActivity as a context.

---

The application handles GPS and Http requests through Volley just fine, but when I added this line

```
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_main, test));
```

it refuses to boot and produce any useful message.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use it completely wrong.

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(CONTEXT,VIEW_ID_TO_SHOW_TEXT, YOUR_LIST)
```

You should not pass `R.layout.activity_main`to it. use :

> android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1

or make your custom layout which is just an Text view.

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, test)
```

Comment: Understood now. The second parameter is the layout going to be used to show the array's content, not the layout in which the drawer is in, as I previously thought. Thanks, it worked :-)

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by Smariz: The second parameter is the view going to be used to show the array's content, not the view in which the drawer is in, as I previously thought.

Create a layout/menu_list.xml to be your adapter template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tv"
android:textColor="#FFF"
android:paddingTop="5sp"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:background="#111"
android:maxLines="1"
android:gravity="left"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

(or simple use one of the ones provided by Android, like android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1)

Refer to it or another layout to be used by the adapter to position your array stuff on screen:

```
drawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.menu_list, yourList));
```